Unable to iterate through Shopify Metafield entry list arrays in Liquid
I'm creating a custom Shopify section to display product specifications using a metafield. My metafield named specs is set as an entry list, with each entry containing arrays for label and description. I want to loop through these arrays and render each label-description pair in a list or table format.
Here’s my current Liquid code:
{% assign specs_list = product.metafields.custom.specs.value %}

<ul>
  {% for spec in specs_list %}
    <li>
      <span>{{ spec.label }}</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>{{ spec.description }}</span>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>


Result:
["Label 1","Label 2","Label 3","Label 4","Label 5"]
["Valeur 1","Valeur 2","Valeur 3","Valeur 4","Valeur 5"]


However, spec.label and spec.description aren’t displaying the way I need, likely due to being detected as arrays within each entry.
Attempts so far: Despite trying various approaches to iterate through the arrays using nested loops, the current code version is the only one that works.
Expected Output: I want to display each label-description pair like this:
Label 1 | Value 1
Label 2 | Value 2
Label 3 | Value 3

I faced the same issue few days back and figured it's just how liquid works. Here's how I solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79068611/15338342

I think this will work:
{% assign labels_raw = product.metafields.custom.specs.labels %}
{% assign values_raw = product.metafields.custom.specs.values %}

{% comment %} Formatting the labels {% endcomment %}
{% assign labels_temp1 = labels_raw | remove: '[' %}
{% assign labels_temp2 = labels_temp1 | remove: ']' %}
{% assign labels_temp3 = labels_temp2 | remove: '"' %}
{% assign formatted_labels = labels_temp3 | split: ',' %}

{% comment %} Formatting the Values {% endcomment %}
{% assign values_temp1 = values_raw | remove: '[' %}
{% assign values_temp2 = values_temp1 | remove: ']' %}
{% assign values_temp3 = values_temp2 | remove: '"' %}
{% assign formatted_values = values_temp3 | split: ',' %}

<ul>
  {% for label in formatted_labels %}
    {% assign index = forloop.index0 %}
    <li>
      <span>{{ label | strip }}</span> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <span>{{ formatted_values[index] | strip }}</span>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

However just wrote this in vsCode, I haven't tested it out.
Let me know if it works or not.

As your elems content in the list is formatted as an array you may outpout values as it:
{% for label in labels %}
    {{ label.first }} {{ label.last }}
{% endfor %}

